# What does Matrix in ℝ^n means?

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider $$A=[||a_k||]$$ such that $$ a_k ∈ ℝ^n$$ then A is matrix in ℝ. What does it mean? Does it mean that A contains only one element?

Comment: I guess the columns are vectors in $\Bbb R^n$.